# WooCommerce - How can I list the same product as a variation and also as a simple product

Tags: plugins

In setting up a new WooCommerce store, I have a number of products that have size variations. (For example - Gizmo #26 in widths: 10mm 15mm 20mm etc.) No problem; Woocommerce can handle this. All of those products will be in a "complete range" category.

My challenge is to offer another category "select products," made up of products from the "complete range" category, but only for one specific variation. (For example - Gizmo #26 in 15mm only)

For inventory control purposes, I would like to have the single/simple product in the "select products" category be managed as part of the inventory represented by the the variation of the equivalent product in the "complete range" category.

A variant of this challenge is defining "sets" made up of specific variations. (For example - Gizmo #26 in 15mm + Gizmo #12 in 20mm + Gizmo #3 in 8mm) I see an extension called Product Bundles that looks promising for this part of the puzzle, but don't know if it can answer the primary question: a single product referencing a variation of another product.

How I can tie these disparate product definitions together for inventory control purposes? A SKU seems the logical answer, but I don't know if WooCommerce is adept at managing inventory by SKU.

THANKS in advance for all suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is definitely in the Product Bundles extension. It can indeed enable single product instances of items that exist as variations of other products. Likewise it maintains inventory control as one hopes.

Answer found in the documentation at http://docs.woothemes.com/document/bundles/
(RTFM!)

Answer (score 0):

I would try the Gravity Forms add-on plugin. At the very least it's way easier to add variations to products than the normal Woocommerce "variations". You'll also need Gravity forms but it's awesome. Here are their links for purchase (I know it costs money but it's worth it):

http://www.woothemes.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/

http://www.gravityforms.com/

Hope it helps.